# NodeJS extract a number from a String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this string `wn123456 kg` for example

I would like to take out only the numbers in this case: `123456`

Comment: Just search for JavaScript Regex. NodeJS works the same since it is JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one - `/\d+/g`. It will extract the number.

```js
const str = 'wn123456 kg';
console.log(/\d+/g.exec(str)[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'wn123456 kg';
var num = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
using `match`

```js
var text = 'wn123456 kg';
var number = text.match(/\d+/);
alert(number);
```

using `replace`

```js
alert('wn123456 kg'.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```